# Convert unicode with utf-8 string as content to str

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x, mojibake, pyquery

I'm using pyquery to parse a page:

```
dom = PyQuery('http://zh.wikipedia.org/w/index.php', {'title': 'CSS', 'printable': 'yes', 'variant': 'zh-cn'})
content = dom('#mw-content-text > p').eq(0).text()
```

but what I get in `content` is a unicode string with utf-8 encoded content:

```
u'\xe5\xb1\x82\xe5\x8f\xa0\xe6\xa0\xb7\xe5\xbc\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8...'
```

how could I convert it to `str` without lost the content?

to make it clear:

I want `conent ==  '\xe5\xb1\x82\xe5\x8f\xa0\xe6\xa0\xb7\xe5\xbc\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8'`

not `conent ==  u'\xe5\xb1\x82\xe5\x8f\xa0\xe6\xa0\xb7\xe5\xbc\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8'`

Comment: You can usually treat unicode strings like normal strings. Is there any reason why you want to convert it?

Comment: Also, for more information about Unicode, ASCII and the like i recommend: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer if I print `content`, I just get some strange strings

Comment: would ``content.encode('utf-8')`` do the trick? Also i think Wikipedia has a proper API to query articles, no need to scrape the website.

Comment: content.encode('utf8') would work to literally do what you ask in the question.

Comment: @aychedee  no....if `content` is `u'\u6129\u6162\u1244'` then I can use `content.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @aychedee: No it won't, that would *double* encode the UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have a `unicode` value with UTF-8 bytes, encode to Latin-1 to preserve the 'bytes':

```
content = content.encode('latin1')
```

because the Unicode codepoints U+0000 to U+00FF all map one-on-one with the latin-1 encoding; this encoding thus interprets your data as literal bytes.

For your example this gives me:

```
>>> content = u'\xe5\xb1\x82\xe5\x8f\xa0\xe6\xa0\xb7\xe5\xbc\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8'
>>> content.encode('latin1')
'\xe5\xb1\x82\xe5\x8f\xa0\xe6\xa0\xb7\xe5\xbc\x8f\xe8\xa1\xa8'
>>> content.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'\u5c42\u53e0\u6837\u5f0f\u8868'
>>> print content.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
层叠样式表
```

`PyQuery` uses either `requests` or `urllib` to retrieve the HTML, and in the case of `requests`, uses the `.text` attribute of the response. This auto-decodes the response data based on the encoding set in a `Content-Type` header alone, or if that information is not available, uses `latin-1` for this (for text responses, but HTML is a text response). You can override this by passing in an `encoding` argument:

```
dom = PyQuery('http://zh.wikipedia.org/w/index.php', encoding='utf8',
              {'title': 'CSS', 'printable': 'yes', 'variant': 'zh-cn'})
```

at which point you'd not have to re-encode at all.

Comment: I had the same problem, but your solution only works from the REPL, not from a script. I had to change it to be like this: content.encode('latin1').decode('utf8').encode('utf8')

Comment: Encoding to UTF-8 is fine if that is what you need in the end. But you can skip the decode then too!

Comment: Well I'll be, I should have tried that so I could save myself some self inflicted trauma to the head. I have to admit though, it still confuses me.

Comment: Thanks！ Been tortured by the same issue for one day!

Comment: thanks a lot for this workaround. I was able to convert tamil unicode to readable format.