# How to convert `u'*ST\u4e1c\u94bd'` to Chinese character in python?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have managed to read a csv file with a column of Chinese characters:

[image]

I can also print the whole series or a number of elements of the column:

[image]

However, when I tried to access individual Chinese string in the series, I only got the following output:

[image]

I tried to following ways, but didn't work out:

[image]

So, my question is how to convert `u'\u5e73\u5b89\u94f6\u884c'` back to `中国平安`?

Thanks

Comment: Just type `print u'\u5e73\u5b89\u94f6\u884c'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it did print the characters correctly! Now, I wonder whether the Chinese character can be display on graph properly.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539807/convert-unicode-with-utf-8-string-as-content-to-str